# Como recuar um label em relação a um Checkbox

Tags: html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Desculpem a simplicidade do problema, mas não sei como fazer isso corretamente... Preciso alinhar o segundo label conforme a imagem abaixo onde indiquei de vermelho. Ele precisa ser recuado e ficar alinhado com o primeiro label superior. Dá para fazer isso sem ter que criar classes CSS?
Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="col-md-12 elemento-linha">
    <input asp-for="@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].ValorBooleanoViewModel.Valor" data-plugin="switchery" data-size="small" type="checkbox" class="validar-cpf-cnpj" />
    <label asp-for="@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].RotuloCampo" class="control-label">@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].RotuloCampo</label>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].DescricaoCampo" class="control-label">@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].DescricaoCampo</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sem CSS extra vc pode usar o grid do próprio Bootstrap. Só precisa passar as duas `labels` para dentro da mesma `div`, e não deixar uma `label` sozinha na div como vc fez. Assim vc pode dividir na `col-xs-1` o `input`, e na `col-xs-11` as `labels`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 elemento-linha">
            <input asp-for="@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].ValorBooleanoViewModel.Valor" data-plugin="switchery" data-size="small" type="checkbox" class="validar-cpf-cnpj" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <label asp-for="@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].RotuloCampo" class="control-label">@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].RotuloCampo</label>
            <br>
            <label asp-for="@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].DescricaoCampo" class="control-label">@configuracaoCampo.ConfiguracoesCamposViewModel[i].DescricaoCampo</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ficou um espaçamento de quase 1 cm entre o checkbox e os 'labels'. É possível removê-lo deixando algo entre uns 3 mm mais ou menos?

Comment: @MasterJR o CSS do Bootstrap 3 é muito limitado, para fazer o que vc quer direto com as propriedade dele vc não vai conseguir. Como vc pediu uma solução apenas com BS sem usa css extra não da para fazer muito melhor que isso. Mas se vc quiser usar CSS crie uma classe por exemplo chamada `d-flex` igual no BS4 e coloque nela `display:flex`. Dessa forma vc pode colocar d-flex na row que vai ter os elementos dentro, e retire a classe col das div, ficaria assim http://prntscr.com/opigy1  com uma linha de CSS vc resolve... Se quiser edite o resposta com essa opção

Answer (score -1):

cara, uma coisa que você pode fazer mas nao sei se seria a melhor pratica mas resolveria seu problema é colocar uma `div` ou um `label` em cima desse input checkbox, ficando entao `<label><input type='checkbox'></label>`, e dae você aumenta o height desse label (p.s.: na pior das hipóteses, só colocar tudo em float:left;)

Comment: Palavras do autor ***"Dá para fazer isso sem ter que criar classes CSS?"*** talvez vc não tenha lido essa parte da pergunta dele...

Comment: entendo como criar class sendo por exemplo <a href='#' class='xxx'> e posteriormente no css .xxx { //cods }, oq falei ai é só uma questão de manipulação, ele nao quer criar classe, mas nao disse que nao queria mexer com css

Comment: Ele está usando Bootstrap, talvez seja por isso que ele deixou claro que não queria css extra, mas entenda como quiser...

Comment: então de um palpite melhor